# has_many with foreign key stored in own table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the model `Parent` that `has_one` `Child`. However, for some logical reason, I need to store foreign key in `Parent` instead of `Child`.

Is it possible to define `has_one` relationship with foreign key in the `Parent` table?

I don't want to define `Parent` `belongs_to` `Child`, because I want to create these objects from `Parent` by defining `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the reason for wanting to store the child id in the parent table.

Answer (score 1):

That is the inverse of `has_one` - that is `belongs_to`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use has_one, because I want to avoid issues when I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I'll update my question to address this.

Comment: @AdamNYC what are these issues you want to avoid?

Comment: It honestly doesn't change the answer. Where the foreign key goes is what type of association you have.

Comment: @MarekLipka : `accepts_nested_attributes_for` won't work if I create parent from child object.

Comment: @sevenseacat It is the constraint that I have (not that I don't know normally it should be the other way around). Could you advise on whether or not it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that work similar to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` may be you could just write your own getter?

```
def child_attributes=(attrs)
  child_id? ? (child = Child.create(attrs)) : child.update_attributes(attrs))
end
```

`child = Child.create(attrs)` doesn't `save` your `Parent` though