# How to store foreign keys in the parent with a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, paper-trail-gem

I need to mimic a standard Rails `has_many` relationship, but with the foreign keys stored in the parent.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This is because I am using [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for versioning, and when I retrieve an earlier version of a @product, I want to see what questions it was associated with.

So far, I'm thinking of creating:

- An association callback that updates a serialized array of question
  ids every time a question is added to or removed from
  @product.questions
- A method that read this array and turns it into a
  collection of questions

Something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  serialize :questions_list, Array

  has_many :questions, :after_add => :update_questions_list, :after_remove => :update_questions_list

  def update_questions_list
    update_column :questions_list, questions.map{|q| q.id}
  end

  def versioned_questions
    questions_list.map{|id| Question.find(id)}
  end

end
```

Then I'd exclusively reference versioned_questions in my other methods.

But this seems a bit hackish and potentially a source of bottlenecks. I'd like to do something natively Railsish if possible, where I get all that ActiveRecord Association goodness automatically. Can I?

BTW there is [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210286/has-many-with-foreign-key-stored-in-own-table) that, from it's title, looks like it answers my question, but it actually relates to `has_one` associations, not `has_many`.

Comment: I think you've been downvoted because this goes against Rails conventions - perhaps the downvoter would detail what it was for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer, using Rails 4's support for PostgresQL's array column type for `questions_list`, was:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :questions, :after_add => :add_to_questions_list, :after_remove => :remove_from_questions_list

  def add_to_questions_list(question)
    update_attribute :questions_list, questions_list << question.id
  end

  def remove_from_questions_list(question)
    update_attribute :questions_list, questions_list.reject{|i| i == question.id}
  end

  def versioned_questions
    questions_list.map{|id| Question.find(id)}
  end

end
```